# Why h1 styling from stylesheet is ignored by React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am learning React and have encountered the following problem. Img and p elements are styled but h1 element is ignored for some reason. Why is that?

```
import "./Body.css" 

img { // inside Body.css
height: 150px }
h1 {
font-size: 15px;
color: red
}
p {
font-size: 15px;
color: red
} // inside Body.css


function Body(){
const imgStyle = {
    marginTop: 45
}


return (
<div style={{paddingTop: 100}} className="container">
    <div style={{paddingTop: 20}} className="row">
        <h1>Overview</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md">
        <p>Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) is an infectious disease caused by a new virus.
            The disease causes respiratory illness (like the flu) with symptoms such as a
            cough, fever, and in more severe cases, difficulty breathing. You can protect
            yourself by washing your hands frequently, avoiding touching your face, and 
            avoiding close contact (1 meter or 3 feet) with people who are unwell.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md">
            <img></img>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Rendered elements]

Comment: Maybe they are already set for the whole body in the index.css. Add `!important` after the css properties, like this `font-size: 15px !important`

Comment: Did you create your app using `npx create-react-app`?

Comment: Yes, I used that command